# how to insert null values by passing annotation in google spanner for node js

Tags: sql, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Not able to insert null values using the below sql statement:

```
const query = {
  sql: 'SELECT * FROM Singers WHERE name = @name AND id = @id',
  params: {
    id: spanner.int(8),
    name: null
  },
  types: {
    id: 'int64',
    name: 'string'
  }
};
```

I am getting the error:
Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: The code field is required for types.

Answer (score 0):

Please try param_types instead of types. BTW, the query will return an empty result because NULL = NULL is always false.

Comment: let queries = [{
    sql:
      'INSERT INTO CM_CUST_CROSSREF (column1,column2) VALUES (@column1, @column2)',
    params:
    {
      column1:'text',
   column2:null
    },
    types: {
      column1: 'string',
   column1:'string',
    }

  }];

  database.runTransaction(async (err, transaction) => {
    if (queries.length != 0) {
      try {
        await transaction.batchUpdate(queries);
        if (transaction.commit()) {
          callback();
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  });

Comment: I am doing batch update for multiple insert queries. But I am getting the below error:

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to insert null values in NodeJS

```
database.runTransaction(async (err, transaction) => {
    const [updateCount] = await transaction.runUpdate({
      sql:
        'INSERT Into Singers (SingerId, FirstName, LastName)' +
        'VALUES (104, @FirstName, @LastName)',
      params: {
        FirstName: "Test",
        LastName: null,
      },
      types: {
        FirstName: 'string',
        LastName: 'string',
      },
    });
  });
```